JSON Schema validation for value '0' fails
I am a bit new to using nodejs to validate a request object with the schema. As long as the value in request object for "from" is not '0' the validation passes. But the moment I use '0' value the validation fails. I have tried debugging and resolving but am unable to resolve the issue. Any help or suggestion is most welcome. I have provided all the relevant details below -
I have below schema snippet from a file schema.json:-
"abc1": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
         "from": {
             "type": "integer",
              "minimum": 0,
              "example": 1796,
              "description": "abc1 in cubic centimetres"
         },
         "to": {
              "type": "integer",
              "minimum": 0,
              "example": 3000,
              "description": "abc1 in cubic centimetres"
         }
    }
}

request model:-
{
  "criteria": {
    "abc1": {
      "from": 0,
      "to": 1700
    }
  }
}

validation.js
const Ajv = require('ajv');
const { BadRequestError } = require('./errors-codes');
const { createErrorResponse } = require('./response-mapper');
const metaSchema = require('./json-schema-draft-04.json');

const defaultAjvOptions = {
    schemaId: '$id',
    allErrors: true,
    verbose: true,
    format: 'full',
};

const validationMiddleware = (schema, inputSchemaPath, ajvOptions = {}) => {
    const ajv = new Ajv({ ...defaultAjvOptions, ...ajvOptions });
    ajv.addMetaSchema(metaSchema);
    //ajv.addSchema(metaSchema, 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#');


    ajv.addSchema(schema, 'schemaRoot');
    const inputValidator = ajv.getSchema(inputSchemaPath);

    const validationMiddlewareBefore = async ({ event, context }) => {
        const { logger } = context;

        try {
            const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
            if (!inputValidator(body)) {
                logger.info('Request does not adhere to schema');
                return createErrorResponse(new BadRequestError(), logger);
            }

            /* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
            event.parsedBody = body;
            /* eslint-enable no-param-reassign */
        } catch (error) {
            logger.info('Request is not valid JSON');
            return createErrorResponse(new BadRequestError(), logger);
        }

        return undefined;
    };

    return {
        before: validationMiddlewareBefore,
    };
};

module.exports = validationMiddleware;

test class:-
const validationMiddleware = require('./validation');
const schema = require('./schema');

const ajvOptions = {};

const middleware = validationMiddleware(schema, 'schemaRoot#/components/schemas/Request', ajvOptions);

test('Validates engineCapacity.from with 0 correctly', async () => {
    const mockEvent = {
        body: JSON.stringify({
            criteria: {
                abc1: {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 3000
                }
            }
        }),
        context: {
            logger: console
        }
    };

    const response = await middleware.before(mockEvent);

    expect(response).toBeUndefined(); 
    expect(mockEvent.parsedBody.criteria.engineCapacity.from).toBe(0);
});

I am getting following error on validation:-
● Test suite failed to run
exclusiveMinimum value must be ["number"]

  14 | const validationMiddleware = (schema, inputSchemaPath, ajvOptions = {}) => {
  15 |     const ajv = new Ajv({ ...defaultAjvOptions, ...ajvOptions });
> 16 |     ajv.addMetaSchema(metaSchema);

json-schema-draft-04.json : -
{
    "$id": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "Core schema meta-schema",
    "definitions": {
        "schemaArray": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": { "$ref": "#" }
        },
        "positiveInteger": {
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 0
        },
        "positiveIntegerDefault0": {
            "allOf": [ { "$ref": "#/definitions/positiveInteger" }, { "default": 0 } ]
        },
        "simpleTypes": {
            "enum": [ "array", "boolean", "integer", "null", "number", "object", "string" ]
        },
        "stringArray": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": { "type": "string" },
            "minItems": 1,
            "uniqueItems": true
        }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "$id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "$schema": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "title": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "default": {},
        "multipleOf": {
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 0,
            "exclusiveMinimum": true
        },
        "maximum": {
            "type": "number"
        },
        "exclusiveMaximum": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false
        },
        "minimum": {
            "type": "number"
        },
        "exclusiveMinimum": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false
        },
        "maxLength": { "$ref": "#/definitions/positiveInteger" },
        "minLength": { "$ref": "#/definitions/positiveIntegerDefault0" },
        "pattern": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "regex"
        },
        "additionalItems": {
            "anyOf": [
                { "type": "boolean" },
                { "$ref": "#" }
            ],
            "default": {}
        },
        "items": {
            "anyOf": [
                { "$ref": "#" },
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/schemaArray" }
            ],
            "default": {}
        },
        "maxItems": { "$ref": "#/definitions/positiveInteger" },
        "minItems": { "$ref": "#/definitions/positiveIntegerDefault0" },
        "uniqueItems": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false
        },
        "maxProperties": { "$ref": "#/definitions/positiveInteger" },
        "minProperties": { "$ref": "#/definitions/positiveIntegerDefault0" },
        "required": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringArray" },
        "additionalProperties": {
            "anyOf": [
                { "type": "boolean" },
                { "$ref": "#" }
            ],
            "default": {}
        },
        "definitions": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": { "$ref": "#" },
            "default": {}
        },
        "properties": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": { "$ref": "#" },
            "default": {}
        },
        "patternProperties": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": { "$ref": "#" },
            "default": {}
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": {
                "anyOf": [
                    { "$ref": "#" },
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringArray" }
                ]
            }
        },
        "enum": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "uniqueItems": true
        },
        "type": {
            "anyOf": [
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/simpleTypes" },
                {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/simpleTypes" },
                    "minItems": 1,
                    "uniqueItems": true
                }
            ]
        },
        "format": { "type": "string" },
        "allOf": { "$ref": "#/definitions/schemaArray" },
        "anyOf": { "$ref": "#/definitions/schemaArray" },
        "oneOf": { "$ref": "#/definitions/schemaArray" },
        "not": { "$ref": "#" }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "exclusiveMaximum": [ "maximum" ],
        "exclusiveMinimum": [ "minimum" ]
    },
    "default": {}
}


If you want 0 to be valid, then you should not use exclusiveMinimum. Use minimum: 0 instead.

Apologies, I have updated the schema above. I forgot to remove it.

The error still refers to exclusiveMinimum. If you're still getting an error, share that new error.

I know and that is what is stumping me a bit because as mentioned I have removed the exclusiveMinimum and yet when I run the test. I get the above error.

Then somehow you're running old code. The error doesn't make sense with the updated schema!

@Evert I have double checked and I am not running the test against an old code. The updated schema no longer has exclusiveMinimum.

I don't know what else to tell you! Go back to basics, test everything! Somewhere in there is an incorrect assumption. Go line by line using a debugger if you have to .

you mean my schema??

couple issues with the usage of Ajv. The errors you are receiving are related to the metaschema, not to your schema or the instance being validated.
Your schema is draft-04 and Ajv uses draft-07 by default, assuming you're using version 8+. $id is only used in newer drafts, draft-04 still used id so you don't need that option defined in the ajv options.
You can use their wrapper for draft-04 and the add-formats package to include all the formats.
Here's a basic example of using ajv. You can adapt it accordingly.
const Ajv = require("ajv-draft-04");
const addFormats = require('ajv-formats');

let schema = {
     "id": "https://example.org/schemas/root",
     "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
     "type": "object",
     "properties": {
          "criteria": {
               "type": "object",
               "properties": {
                    "abc1": {
                         "type": "object",
                         "properties": {
                              "from": {
                                   "type": "integer",
                                   "minimum": 0,
                                   "example": 1796,
                                   "description": "abc1 in cubic centimetres"
                              },
                              "to": {
                                   "type": "integer",
                                   "minimum": 0,
                                   "example": 3000,
                                   "description": "abc1 in cubic centimetres"
                              }
                         }
                    }
               }
          }
     }
};

let data = {
  "criteria": {
    "abc1": {
      "from": 0,
      "to": 1700
    }
  }
};

try {

   let ajv = new Ajv({strict: false, allErrors: true});
   addFormats(ajv);
   validate = ajv.compile(schema);

   let valid = validate(data);

  console.log(
    (results = {
      valid: valid,
      error: validate.errors
    })
  );
} catch (err) {
 console.error(err.message);
  
};


Thank you, but what I do not understand as why would the value '0' be not validated with original implementation whereas the validation works for all other values?

i'm pretty sure it wasn't working to begin with

I can confirm that that the original is working for all positive values except '0'. I am even able to validate the schema schema for a negative value. :(
